# php preg_match_all: split list items and child lists

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, preg-match-all, listitem

I'm trying to split some html content using php's `preg-match-all` function:

```
<li class="cat-item"><a title="blabla" href="#">parent 1</a>
    <ul class="children">
        <li class="cat-item"><a title="" href="#">child 1</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-4"><a title="blabla" href="#">father 2</a>
    <ul class="children">
        <li class="cat-item"><a title="" href="#">child 1</a></li>
        <li class="cat-item"><a title="bla" href="#">child 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I want to be able to change the link description, for example;

```
<a title="" href="#">child 1</a>
```

to

```
<a title="" href="#">I changed that</a>
```

while keeping the structure of the original html.
so far, I succeeded to split the links using :

```
$results = preg_match_all('/<a\s[^>]*href\s*=\s*(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/siU', $html, $tokens); 

foreach ( $tokens[0] as $category)
{
    echo $category.'<br>';
}
```

the drawback of this is that it discards child lists, and outputs all the list items in the same level; no distinction between parent and child.

any idea to keep original hierarchy?

thanx :)

Comment: That is a very hard job for a regexp to do, would be better served with an HTML parser in this case (I am very pro-regexp, and normally fight their corner, but on this sort of nesting, it is an uphill struggle).  What exactly do you wish to put in to the anchors?

Comment: thanx Orbling, I agree that regexp is not the right way to go when parsing html, I started playing with the domDocument, but not getting to my point so far..
what I want to achieve is related to wordpress's wp_list_categories() function; I need to translate the echoed results; this function doesn't have a return value of array or object, but only echo :(  so I try to create a dirthy fix for that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use preg_replace to replace strings! something like this here:

```
$output = preg_replace("/^([123]0|[012][1-9]|31)(\\.|-|\/|,)(0[1-9]|1[012])(\\.|-|\/)(19[0-9]{2}|2[0-9]{3})$/","$1",$in_nn_date);
```

where $1 or $2 is the thing you have searched with regex and grouped in.

best would be that you use some online editor or something... like [this one](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

and try there! hope it helps...

Comment: Thanx FeRtoll,
I think I need more than regular expressions to solve this, since I need to recreate the original output hierarchy.